# Tensorflow: Py_func returns unknown shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a simple question re the `tf.py_func` function.

I have an image tensor `my_img` of shape `(1,224,224,3)`. To test `py_func`, I feed the tensor to a python function `return_tf` that should give back the same tensor (after being converted to a numpy array as per docs).

Here's the code:

```
def return_tf(x):
   return np.array(x)

test = tf.py_func(return_tf,[my_img],[tf.float32])
```

But when I checked the shape of the returned tensor called `test`, I get:

```
tf.Tensor 'PyFunc:0' shape=unknown dtype=float32
```

I am also unable to run `eval()` on the tensor, since I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'eval'.
```

Anyone knows how could I fix the tensor shape of the tensor returned by `tf.py_func`?

Answer (score 5):

Just found a work-around.. since py_func returns a tensorflow list, I can do the ff:

```
test = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, test), [ <<a shape>> ])
```

to get a tensor with a desired shape