# Output from TensorFlow `py_func` has unknown rank/shape

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a simple neural net in TensorFlow. The only tricky part is I have a custom operation that I have implemented with `py_func`. When I pass the output from `py_func` to a `Dense` layer, TensorFlow complains that the rank should be known. The specific error is:

```py
ValueError: Inputs to `Dense` should have known rank.
```

I don't know how to preserve the shape of my data when I pass it through `py_func`. My question is how do I get the correct shape? I have a simple example below to illustrate the problem.

```py
def my_func(x):
    return np.sinh(x).astype('float32')

inp = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(5))
y = tf.py_func(my_func, [inp], tf.float32, False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with sess.as_default():
        print(inp.shape)
        print(inp.eval())
        print(y.shape)
        print(y.eval())
```

The output from this snippet is:

```py
(5,)
[0 1 2 3 4]
<unknown>
[  0.       
1.17520118   3.62686038  10.01787472  27.28991699]
```

Why is `y.shape` `<unknown>`? I want the shape to be `(5,)` the same as `inp`. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: Py\_func returns unknown shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992445/tensorflow-py-func-returns-unknown-shape)

Comment: @gkcn Maybe, it's been a while since I asked but I found that question which the author answered himself. I remember his solution not working for me which is why I wrote my question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since `py_func` can execute arbitrary Python code and output anything, TensorFlow can't figure out the shape (it would require analyzing Python code of function body) You can instead give the shape manually

```
y.set_shape(inp.get_shape())
```