# tf.train.shuffle_batch() ValueError: Cannot infer Tensor's rank: Tensor("PyFunc:0", dtype=uint8)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to feed my image data from my `TFRecord` files into `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`.  I have a `load_img_file()` function that reads the `TFRecord` files, does preprocessing, and returns the images and one-hot labels in the format [[array of images, `np.uint8` format], [array of labels, `np.uint8` format]].  I made the op

```
load_img_file_op = tf.py_func(self.load_img_file, [], [np.uint8, np.uint8])
```

which converts that function into an op.  I have verified that that op works by doing

```
data = tf.Session().run(load_img_file_op)
for n in range(50): #go through images
    print data[1][n] #print one-hot label
    self.image_set.display_img(data[0][n]) #display image
```

which successfully prints the one-hot labels and displays the corresponding images.

However, when I try to do something like

```
self.batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(load_img_file_op, batch_size=self.batch_size, capacity=q_capacity, min_after_dequeue=10000)
```

I get the error

> raise ValueError("Cannot infer Tensor's rank: %s" % tl[i])
>   ValueError: Cannot infer Tensor's rank: Tensor("PyFunc:0", dtype=uint8)"

I have tried many variations to try to match what the guide does:

- Instead of `self.batch =`, I have tried example_batch, `label_batch =` (trying to get two values instead of one)
- setting `enqueue_many` to True
- having my `load_image_file()` function and `load_img_file_op` return two separate values: `images` and `labels`. And then inputting them like `tf.train.shuffle_batch([images, labels],...)`
- returning/inputting just one image and label at a time into `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`
- using `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join()`

Nothing seems to work, but I feel like I am following the format of the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) and various other tutorials I have seen.  What am I doing wrong?  I apologize if my mistake is stupid or trivial (searches for this error do not seem to return anything relevant to me). Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: You might want to have a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape) in the comments helped a lot; thank you!  (The answer is that you have to give the shape when using py_func.)  Since I had to figure out a little bit more on top of that I will post the complete solution:

I had to make my function return two separate values so that they would be two different tensors and could be shaped separately:

```
return images, labels
```

Then, proceeding as in the question above, but shaping:

```
load_img_file_op = tf.py_func(self.load_img_file, [], [np.uint8, np.uint8]) # turn the function into an op
images, labels = load_img_file_op
images.set_shape([imgs_per_file, height * width])
labels.set_shape([imgs_per_file, num_classes])
self.batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([images, labels], batch_size=self.batch_size, capacity=q_capacity, min_after_dequeue=1000, enqueue_many = True)
```

The `enqueue_many` is important so that the images will enter the queue individually.