# Dataset API does not pass dimensionality information for its output tensor when using py_func

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

To reproduce my problem, try this first (mapping with py_func):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def image_parser(image_name):
    a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0], dtype=np.float32)
    return a

images = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
im_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
im_dataset = im_dataset.map(lambda image:tuple(tf.py_func(image_parser, [image], [tf.float32])), num_parallel_calls = 2)
im_dataset = im_dataset.prefetch(4)
iterator = im_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
print(im_dataset.output_shapes)
```

It will give you `(TensorShape(None),)`

However, if you try this (using direct tensorflow mapping instead of py_func):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def image_parser(image_name)
    return image_name

images = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
im_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
im_dataset = im_dataset.map(image_parser)
im_dataset = im_dataset.prefetch(4)
iterator = im_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
print(im_dataset.output_shapes)
```

It will give you the exact tensor dimension (3,)

Answer (score 9):

This is a general problem with `tf.py_func` which is intended since TensorFlow cannot infer the output shape itself, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape).

You could set the shape yourself if you need to, by moving the `tf.py_func` inside the parse function:

```py
def parser(x):
    a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
    y = tf.py_func(lambda: a, [], tf.float32)
    y.set_shape((3,))
    return y

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset = dataset.map(parser)
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # will correctly print (3,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: solution only works in some cases. tf eager and auto trying to wrap of some functions makes this messy :/

Comment: @SumNeuron If you have problems with Autograph, try putting the `set_shape` in a separate `map` after the python function `map`.