# Tensorflow data map with py_func results in ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a py_func in my dataset.map callback that returns a sample weight. See this example:

```
def get_sample_weight(team, number):
    # Some code
    return np.array([0.5]).astype(np.float32) #return weight

def preprocess_tfrecord_example(example, sample_weights):
    image = tf.image.decode_png(example['detection/encoded'])
    team = example['detection/team_name']

    sample_weight = tf.py_func(get_sample_weight, [team, example['detection/number']], tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize_image_with_pad(image,56,108)

    number = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(example['detection/number'], tf.float32), -1)
    return image/255., number, sample_weight
```

However, when I create the dataset and call model.fit(dataset, ....) this gives

> ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.

This is because Tensorflow cannot determine the shape returned by the python function, see [Output from TensorFlow `py_func` has unknown rank/shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape).

As a workaround I try to set the shape with `sample_weight.set_shape(1)` before returning it in preprocess_tfrecord_example(..).

But this gives

> ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (?, 1). In order to use timestep-wise sample weights, you should specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile(). If you just mean to use sample-wise weights, make sure your sample_weight array is 1D.

How can I set the right shape, such that the sample_weight array for use in model.fit is 1D?

Comment: are you batching your data before you feed to model fit?

Comment: yes, I fixed it by adding an extra dataset.map where I do the reshape