# Tensorflow py_function setting return value shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am tring to set the shape of an numpy array return from a `tf.py_function` call. Function returns a tuple of array and its shape, so I can set its shape inside `tf.function`. However I can not use the returned shape array inside a set_shape call. I tried casting it to int32 or accessing it via indices etc. but all results in a `TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>' with type '<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>'` error.

```
@tf.function
def samples(img, mask) -> tuple:
    xs, xs_shape = tf.py_function(process,[128, 128], [tf.float32, tf.int32])
    xs.set_shape(tf.TensorShape(xs_shape))
    return xs

ds = ds.map(samples)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a contrived example. I assume this could be your requirement.

```
def f(x):
    print("print ", x)
    # Include Logic using 'x' which is a tensor.
    # Sample  return values
    return [tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2]), tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2]).shape]


@tf.function
def samples(x) -> tuple:
    xs, xs_shape = f(x)
    xs.set_shape(xs_shape)
    print( xs_shape)
    return xs

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 6)
dataset = dataset.map(  samples )
```

Comment: This still results in the same error. problem is when f is called with tf.py_function that causes the problem. I need py_function cause I need access to numpy

Comment: Simplified code is in the question. In your example if you just change your f(x) call to  tf.py_function call you will get the same error. `tf.py_function(f,[x], [tf.float32, tf.int32])`

Comment: I am not sure if that is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape). numpy can be used in the function  I've shown but I don't know your logic.